# Combining time & date in golang?

Tags: go

Suppose I have

```
t := time.Parse("15:04:05.000", "12:16:54.016")
```

This returns a time.Time which prints out as:

```
0000-01-01 12:16:54.016 +0000 UTC
```

But I know what the actual date is and have it stored as a variable called `timestamp` which is a time.Time struct already. How do I combine them?

e.g. suppose the date is 2019-06-17.  I need the output to be:

2019-06-17 12:16:54.016 +0000 UTC

```
// this doesn't compile
ts.AddDate(timestamp.Year(), timestamp.Month(), timestamp.Day())


cannot use timestamp.Month() (type time.Month) as type int in argument to ts.AddDate
```

This should be trivial right?  well it is in C which is what I'm most used to.  But I haven't found the answer easily for golang.  The docs don't tell me the actual underlying field names, just functions.  :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the `Date` in string format, combine the entire date-time into a single string and call `time.Parse` once:

```
func datePlusTime(date, timeOfDay string) (time.Time, error) {
    return time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000", date+" "+timeOfDay)
}

func main() {
    t, err := datePlusTime("2019-06-17", "12:16:54.016")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Output:

> 2019-06-17 12:16:54.016 +0000 UTC

https://play.golang.org/p/kbor6NBMFLl

---

If the date is not in a string format - but you have it in a `time.Time`, simply coerce to the desired string format, like so:

```
mydate.Format("2006-01-02") // e.g. mydate:= time.Now()
```

Comment: This isn't inherently simpler, and it doesn't solve the TZ math problem--it just moves it.

Comment: @Flimzy agreed. In the OP It's unclear where the the TZ info is: in the date (time.Time) or should it be relayed via the time-of-day input (if we're not dealing with UTC?). _So for all the kids watching at home: always store your times in UTC!_

Answer (score 3):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    d, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", "2019-06-17")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(d)

    t, err := time.Parse("15:04:05.000", "12:16:54.016")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(t)

    f := d.Add(time.Hour*time.Duration(t.Hour()) + time.Minute*time.Duration(t.Minute()) + time.Second*time.Duration(t.Second()) + time.Nanosecond*time.Duration(t.Nanosecond()))
    fmt.Println(f)
}
```